# Is there a way to make report filters mandatory

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, civireport, 4.7, custom-reports

I have made some custom reports which contain two types of filters:

1. a date field. This does not correspond to a database field. Its
   just used in some calculations
2. some custom fields

Is it possible to make these filters mandatory? Defaulting the values doesn't really help.

OR is it possible for the report to produce a custom error message which the user can see if the field is not set? For example, in the custom report if the filter values are not set then set error message and stop running the report.

Answer (score 1):

If you are setting the filter value (with a default) and don't want the user to change it, you can use the 'no_display' parameter to hide the filter from the user.  (Per the docs here: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviReport+Reference#CiviReportReference-filters ) Unfortunately, it doesn't look like the Required parameter is an option for filters like it is for fields.